# JavaFX: How to show an Alert Confirmation before a property value is changed?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, alert, changelistener

I have a JavaFX Application with many UI-Elements like Buttons, Sliders, TextFields and so on. I have a certain group of UI-Elements that I want the user to be able to change but only after he confirmed once, that he is sure he wants to change them. Any attempted change to any of those elements should be discarded, if the user does not confirm that he knows what he's doing.

I've made a very simple mockup.

```
public class App extends Application {

    private Label label;
    boolean changeConfirmed = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        VBox container = new VBox();
        Button button = new Button("Something");
        Slider slider = new Slider(0,1,0.5);
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        label = new Label("Empty");

        // Here should be the code I'm asking for

        container.getChildren().addAll(button,slider,textField);
        pane.setRight(container);
        pane.setCenter(label);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,400,300);
        stage.setTitle("Alert Test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private void handle(String string) {
        label.setText(string);
    }

    private boolean changeConfirmed(){
        if(changeConfirmed) {
            return true;
        }
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Confirm Change");
        alert.setHeaderText("A change occurred.");
        alert.setContentText("Do you really want to change the value?");
        Optional<ButtonType> buttonType = alert.showAndWait();
        if(buttonType.isPresent() && buttonType.get().equals(ButtonType.OK)) {
            changeConfirmed = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want that, as long as the boolean changeConfirmed is false, any attempted change to any of the UI elements is interrupted by the changeConfirmed()-Method. Once the method returned true, the boolean is true and no further confirmation is needed (it would otherwise become very tiresome to confirm all changes for every UI-Element). The boolean changeConfirmed is made false again at a later time in the program and not relevant here.

What is absolut important to me is that the value of the property doesn't change before the confirmation has been passed.

I've tried using ChangeListeners (obviously) but to my knowledge, the value of the property has already been changed when the listener is executed. So the Alert comes to late (I might be wrong here, it's my current understanding)

I've also tried InvalidationListeners. Those seem to be processed before a change to the property is actually made, but I don't know how to make sure that the property's value doesn't change if the change-Alert is not confirmed.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: So just do it. In the event handler for the button, just have `if (! changeConfirmed) { /* show confirm dialog */}` followed by `if (changeConfirmed) { /* make changes */}`. You don't need any listeners here; just put the logic in the event handler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work like I want. I added this to the slider:
`slider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
if (!changeConfirmed) { changeConfirmed();}
if (changeConfirmed) { handle(newValue.toString());}
});`
But even if I don't confirm the alert, the slider value has changed. The little slider button should remain where it was before it was dragged. A TextField should not change it's content and so on.

Comment: *"The little slider button should remain where it was before it was dragged. A TextField should not change it's content and so on"* If a text field can't change its value, how is the user supposed to type in it. If you want to revert the values, then just write the logic to do that. There is no magic here, the toolkit will only do what you program it to do.

Comment: Or (additionally) just disable most/all the input controls until and unless the user confirms they know what they're doing. You could do this by making `changeConfirmed` a `BooleanProperty` and then binding the `disable` property of each control to it. And if you don't like the look of disabled controls, you can always change the style.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still trying to wrap my head around how all of this works. I thought that manually setting the value back to it's original, after the change event fired, would just create a new event because the value got changed again. Resulting in an endless "stack" of changed values, trying to get confirmed.

Comment: @Slaw I've already experimented with that approach because it seems much easier. My application is a simulator of some sort and while the simulation is running, I actually do disable all simulation parameter controls (since they absolutely can not change while a simulation is running). When the simulation is paused though, the user should be allowed to change the settings, but he has to confirm that by doing so, he resets the whole simulation and looses all of the progress so far. That is why I want to chose this approach laid out here.

Comment: If you’re only responding to “actions”, such as action events on buttons and text fields, or the `valueChanging` property changing to false on a slider, then those won’t be triggered by changing the control’s value.

Comment: Well, you could add another button to put the UI in "edit mode". It would first confirm the user knows the consequences before entering that mode. And this button would only be displayed while the UI is in "read-only mode" and the simulation is paused.

Comment: @Slaw Yeah, I see. That would also work.

Comment: If you had a Presentation Model to hold the values from the GUI, then you could probably create a custom Binding with a Confirmation type Alert in the updateValue() method.  You might be able to get it to reset the value if it's bidirectional.  You could also look into using DirtyFX for your Presentation Model, to detect changes that way (this is probably the best way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check in the handlers for the controls if `changeConfirmed` is false; if it is show the confirm dialog. Then, still in the event handler, check again if `changeConfirmed` is true; if it is, change the value. If you want to revert the value in the control if the users denies confirmation, then write the code for that.

Here is a quick example based loosely on your example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    private boolean changeConfirmed = false ;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        HBox nameBox = new HBox(5);
        HBox ageBox = new HBox(5);
        Label nameLabel = new Label();
        Label ageLabel = new Label();
        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setMin(0);
        slider.setMax(120);
        TextField nameTF = new TextField();

        slider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((obs, isFinishedChanging, isNowChanging) -> {
            if (isFinishedChanging) {
                if (!changeConfirmed) {
                    showConfirmDialog();
                }
                if (changeConfirmed) {
                    ageLabel.setText(String.valueOf((int)slider.getValue()));
                } else {
                    // revert to current value:
                    String ageStr = ageLabel.getText();
                    int age = ageStr.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(ageStr);
                    slider.setValue(age);
                }
            }
        });

        nameTF.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (! changeConfirmed) {
                showConfirmDialog();
            }
            if (changeConfirmed) {
                nameLabel.setText(nameTF.getText());
            } else {
                nameTF.setText(nameLabel.getText());
            }
        });

        nameBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Name:"), nameLabel);
        ageBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Age:"), ageLabel);

        Button clearConfirm = new Button("Request to confirm changes");
        clearConfirm.setOnAction(e -> changeConfirmed = false);

        root.getChildren().addAll(nameBox, ageBox, nameTF, slider, clearConfirm);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void showConfirmDialog() {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Confirm Change");
        alert.setHeaderText("A change occurred.");
        alert.setContentText("Do you really want to change the value?");
        Optional<ButtonType> buttonType = alert.showAndWait();
        if(buttonType.isPresent() && buttonType.get().equals(ButtonType.OK)) {
            changeConfirmed = true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm just trying out your solution and it works for the slider very well. I'm still experimenting with the textfield, since my "wrong" inputs remain as text. I'd like to have the confirmation show up as soon as the user starts typing (and subsequently setting the label with every keystroke once the confirmation has been passed)

Comment: @Wewius You want to show a confirmation dialog *on every keystroke* in a text field????

Comment: No, no. Say the user starts typing the first letter. I want him to confirm that what he's doing is correct and after that the boolean is set to true, so every keystroke after that is automatically allowed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Wewius Added "revert to current value" behavior on the text field. But I didn't make it respond immediately on a text change; I think that's a ridiculous UX

Comment: Note that if you have a properly separated MVC design, the labels here really stand in place of the model. That separation makes this fairly natural to code.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm using MVC design in my actual application. I just made this example really quick to get my point across.

Right now the user has to confirm every TextField with "Enter" to trigger the onAction-Event. I'd like the user to be able to click into a TextField , type something (and confirm it), tab into the next field and so on... Without hitting enter every time.

Comment: @Wewius OK, but typically in any UI application typing in a text field and tabbing to the next control wouldn't change the model; you'd only change the model when the user "commits" a change. You can show your confirm dialog when they commit, in whatever way that is.

Comment: For a TextField you should probably use a TextFormatter.  Then you can check via Dialog in the Filter.